# Visual studio language support for style has not install

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015, my problem is on opening aspx file first time on project loading this warning popups.

Please Help me how to solve this issue.
i am attaching screen shot.
[image]

Comment: close the visualstudio and open Run and type this `Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`

Comment: This fixed the same issue in VS 2019 16.5.0 preview 4.0